# How to restructure loops in banking method

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement, methods, while-loop

I'm currently trying to write a method that will first ask for a deposit, withdraw, or quit.

Then ask for the account name (this fetches the account from the array list by the name)

Then prompt for an amount for the selected deposit or withdraw.

Then return back to the (deposit, withdraw, quit) prompt

The code I have written is in the wrong order. (It asks for the name, then the action, then the amount), and I can't work out how to change it to the desired order above.

I also can't work out how to get the loop to quit on an input of 3.

I think I'm close... just can't seem to move forward from here.
(ps the while true loop is just a temporary loop I was using while I tried to figure out the rest)

```
public void banking()
{
    while(true)
    {          
        Scanner scan4 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("please enter the name for the account"); //takes the name of the account to select the correct object in arraylist
        String accountName = scan4.nextLine();

        for(Account y: accounts)                                    //for all the objects in the arraylist...
        {
            while(accountName.equalsIgnoreCase(y.getName()))
            {
                Scanner scan3 = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("1:Deposit   2:Withdraw  3:Quit");
                int request = scan3.nextInt();

                if(request == 1)
                {
                    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
                    System.out.println("please make a deposit");
                    double newBalance = scan.nextDouble();
                    y.deposit(newBalance);
                }

                else if (request == 2)
                {
                    Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(System.in);
                    System.out.println("please make a withdrawl");
                    double withdrawl = scan2.nextDouble();

                    if(withdrawl > y.getBalance())
                    {
                        System.out.println("Insufficient funds");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        y.withdraw(withdrawl);
                    }
                }
                else if (request == 3)
                {
                   break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you just want to change the order to the following:

1. Action (deposit, withdraw, quit)
2. Account Name
3. Amount (only deposit/withdraw)

This can easily be achieved by scanning for the action at the beginning of the method.
So you just have to move this part to the beginning of your wile-loop:

```
Scanner scan3 = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("1:Deposit   2:Withdraw  3:Quit");
int request = scan3.nextInt();
```

Additionally you have to change your seconde while-loop to an if-statement. Otherwise, the loop won't stop once you entered it, and it would not be possible to choose a different action.

So change this:

```
while(accountName.equalsIgnoreCase(y.getName()))
```

To this:

```
if(accountName.equalsIgnoreCase(y.getName()))
```

So the corrected code would look like this:

```
public void banking()
{
    while(true)
    {
    Scanner scan3 = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("1:Deposit   2:Withdraw  3:Quit");
    int request = scan3.nextInt();

    Scanner scan4 = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("please enter the name for the account"); //takes the name of the account to select the correct object in arraylist
    String accountName = scan4.nextLine();

    for(Account y: accounts)                                    //for all the objects in the arraylist...
    {
        if(accountName.equalsIgnoreCase(y.getName()))
        {
            if(request == 1)
                {
                    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
                    System.out.println("please make a deposit");
                    double newBalance = scan.nextDouble();
                    y.deposit(newBalance);
                }

            else if (request == 2)
                {
                    Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(System.in);
                    System.out.println("please make a withdrawl");
                    double withdrawl = scan2.nextDouble();

                    if(withdrawl > y.getBalance())
                        {
                            System.out.println("Insufficient funds");
                        }
                    else
                        {
                            y.withdraw(withdrawl);
                        }


                }

            else if (request == 3)
                {
                   break;
                }
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Also there can be made further improvements for the efficiency. For example by avoiding the for-loop if the user chose "quit". (but this is optional and not necessary)

Even though this would solve your problem, I have to tell you that you should never ever use `true` as a condition for a while-loop.

Comment: Oh, I just read your statement regarding the while(true) loop ...
Just ignore my last sentence :)

Comment: Thank you, this has been a good step closer for what I'm trying to achieve!

Comment: You're welcome.
Feel free to ask further questions if you need some more help :)

Comment: well... if you're offering ;) i was wondering, is there any alternative to using equalsIgnoreCase?

Comment: I think in this case `equalsIgnoreCase()` is the best way to go.
You could also apply `toLowerCase()` to both strings before comparing them, but this would be unnecessary complicated.

Answer (score 0):

From you code i understand that `accounts` is an `arrayList` of `Account`.

If so then you can remove this `while` condition

```
while(accountName.equalsIgnoreCase(y.getName()))
        {
```

and use `if` instead

```
if(accountName.equalsIgnoreCase(y.getName()))
        {
```

This can be one of the points for restructuring.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `switch()` like this:

```
interface Account {
    String getName();

    BigDecimal getBalance();

    void deposit(BigDecimal value);

    void withdraw(BigDecimal value);
}

enum Action {
    DEPOSIT(1),
    WITHDRAW(2),
    QUIT(3),
    UNRECOGNIZED(0);

    private final int value;

    Action(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public static Action getAction(int value) {
        for (Action action : Action.values()) {
            if (action.getValue() == value) {
                return action;
            }
        }
        return UNRECOGNIZED;
    }
}

private static Account getAcc(List<Account> accounts, String acc) {
    return accounts.stream().filter(account -> account.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(acc)).findFirst()
            .orElseThrow(RuntimeException::new);
}

public static void banking(List<Account> accounts) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("please enter number for given action:");
    System.out.println("1 - : deposit");
    System.out.println("2 - : withdraw");
    System.out.println("3 - : quit");

    Action action = Action.getAction(scanner.nextInt());

    if (Action.QUIT == action){
        System.out.println("quiting ...");
        return;
    }


    System.out.println("please enter the name for the account");
    String accountName = scanner.nextLine();
    Account account = getAcc(accounts, accountName);

    switch (action) {
    case WITHDRAW:
        System.out.println("please make a withdrawl");
        BigDecimal withdrawl = new BigDecimal(scanner.nextDouble());
        if (withdrawl.compareTo(account.getBalance()) > 0) {
            System.out.println("Insufficient funds");
        } else {
            account.withdraw(withdrawl);
        }
        break;
    case DEPOSIT:
        System.out.println("please make a deposit");
        BigDecimal newBalance = new BigDecimal(scanner.nextDouble());
        account.deposit(newBalance);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```